# Why does this step in thermodynamics derivations mathematically make sense?

Tags: calculus

In thermodynamics, $h=u+pv$. In certain derivations, this is often done: $dh=du+vdp+pdv$.

Now, in the case of some $f(h) = u(h)v(h)$, I can see how you can differentiate both sides with respect to $h$, and through the definition of a differential in single variable calculus, arrive at $df = udv + vdu$, where you can interpret these differentials as being linear approximations at that point.

But in the thermodynamics case, $u$ and $h$ aren't single variable functions. $p$ and $v$ aren't functions of some $h$ like above. So I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way to interpret $\mathrm{d}h$ is as the total differential of $h(u,p,v) = u+pv$, so that

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d} h = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u}\,\mathrm{d}u + \frac{\partial  h}{\partial p}\,\mathrm{d}p + \frac{\partial h}{\partial v}\,\mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{d}u + v\,\mathrm{d}p + p\,\mathrm{d}v.
\end{equation*}

*Edit*: Keep in mind that the picture looks different in multivariable calculus. For example, let $f(x,y,z)$ be a sufficiently well-behaved function. Then the *definition* of the total differential of $f$ is

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\mathrm{d}y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,\mathrm{d}z.
\end{equation*}

But if $f(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z)h(x,y,z)$, the product rule (for the case of partial derivatives) holds, and so

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}f = \mathrm{d}(gh) = \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}h+g\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}h+g\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)\,\mathrm{d}y + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}h+g\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z.
\end{equation*}

In this way, the familiar product rule sort of generalizes to the total differential.

So in the case that $f(p,v) = pv$

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}(pv) &= \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial p}v+p\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}\right)\,\mathrm{d}p + \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}v+p\frac{\partial v}{\partial v}\right)\,\mathrm{d}v = v\,\mathrm{d}p + p\,\mathrm{d}v
\end{align*}

because, in the thermodynamic definition of enthalpy as $h = u + pv$, $p$ and $v$ (and $u$) are viewed as independent variables.

The confusion arises when referring to the total differential of $g(x,y,z)h(x,y,z)$

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}(gh) = g\,\mathrm{d}h + h\,\mathrm{d}g
\end{equation*}

as the product rule. This is justifiable, though. By definition, we have

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}g = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\,\mathrm{d}y + \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}h = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\,\mathrm{d}y + \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\,\mathrm{d}z.
\end{equation*}

Therefore, the product rule implies that

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}(gh) &= \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}h+g\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}h+g\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\right)\,\mathrm{d}y + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}h+g\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\right)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=g\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}\,\mathrm{d}y + \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\,\mathrm{d}z\right) + h\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\,\mathrm{d}y + \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)\\
&= g\,\mathrm{d}h + h\,\mathrm{d}g.
\end{align*}

This is of course generalizable to functions of more than three independent variables, but in any event, this can be taken as the product rule when dealing with total differentials.

Comment: This makes sense. But the way it is often presented is $dh=d(u +pv) = du+d(pv) = du+vdp+pdv$. So is this incorrect, or what's the way to interpret the way it is often presented?

Comment: @xasthor I don't think it's incorrect, but what part seems incorrect to you? I think it's potentially confusing to think of $\mathrm{d}(pv) =v\, \mathrm{d}p + p\,\mathrm{d}v$ as a plain application of the product rule. Instead, it might be helpful to think of $f(p,v) = pv$ so that $\mathrm{d}f = \mathrm{d}(pv) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\,\mathrm{d}p + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\,\mathrm{d}v = v\,\mathrm{d}p + p\,\mathrm{d}v$.

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense. Yeah, it was the "by product rule" part that was confusing to me. And that's the reason given for that step as well. So would that part be incorrect then?

Comment: @xasthor I don't think it's incorrect, but it might be an unfamiliar use of the term "product rule." Let me know if my edit to my answer helps at all--it really is a consequence of the product rule that $\mathrm{d}(pv) = v\,\mathrm{d}p + p\,\mathrm{d}v$, but it's not necessarily trivial.

Comment: The way you have arrived at the result is still using the definition of the total differential, just that for evaluating the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}$ you have used the product rule for partial derivatives. This is not the same as using the "product rule" to get from $d(pv)$ to $pdv+vdp$. I don't see how that's equivalent. At least in this context, how it's often presented then, appears to be incorrect to me.

Comment: @xasthor does this most recent edit help at all?

Comment: Yes, it's more clear now. The use of the product rule is more subtle than implied usually however. This is how it should be taught, where the definition of the total differential is used, and then the partial derivative terms then reduce to g and h respectively via the product rule for partial derivatives, like you've done